# Resume flowable converted to live data after screen rotation

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Say I have an activity like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TextView countdown = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(countdown);

        ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(TestViewModel.class)
                .getCountdown()
                .observe(this, countdown::setText);
    }
}
```

And the view model is:

```
class TestViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final LiveData<String> countdown =
            LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
                    Flowable.concat(
                            Flowable.just("Falcon Heavy rocket will launch in..."),
                            Flowable.intervalRange(0, 10, 3, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .map(x -> String.valueOf(10 - x)),
                            Flowable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .map(ignored -> "Lift off!")
                    )
            );

    LiveData<String> getCountdown() {
        return countdown;
    }
}
```

I want to handle the rotation correctly, so if the user rotates his device while the countdown says 5, I want the next value after rotation to be 5 (or 4 if the second elapsed already), just pick up wherever the countdown should actually be.

If the rocket has already lifted off, I want it to keep it that way after rotation, I don't want the countdown to start again.

At the moment, `LiveDataReactiveStreams` cancels the subscription on pause and makes a new subscription on resume, so the countdown gets restarted.

I'm guessing I should change something in my RxJava part of the code for this to work. Any ideas as to what to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Svyatoslav Lebeckiy over at [Android United Slack channel](http://android-united.community/) who pointed out `BehaviorSubject` and `BehaviorProcessor` to me and proposed an idea on how to fix this.

I changed my view model to:

```
class TestViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private LiveData<String> countdown;

    LiveData<String> getCountdown() {
        if (countdown == null) {
            countdown = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(startCountdown());
        }
        return countdown;
    }

    private static Flowable<String> startCountdown() {
        final BehaviorProcessor<String> processor = BehaviorProcessor.create();
        Flowable.concat(
                Flowable.just("Falcon Heavy rocket will launch in..."),
                Flowable.intervalRange(0, 10, 3, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .map(x -> String.valueOf(10 - x)),
                Flowable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .map(ignored -> "Lift off!")
        ).subscribe(processor);
        return processor;
    }
}
```

This way I can start the countdown only once in `getCountdown` and the `BehaviorProcessor` created in `startCountdown` takes care of delivering the last and subsequently emitted values to its subscribers (`LiveData` in this case).

Since `LiveDataReactiveStreams` needs a `Flowable`, it's convenient to use a `BehaviorProcessor` instead of `BehaviorSubject` here.